# Php recursive function return null while variable have value

Tags: php, recursion

This function returns NULL while $alias having a value in the second recursion.

In the first call, it returns the required value, but when the first *if* does not match and it recurse first, the required value is available in the $alias variable, but it does not return anything.

```
public function checkAlias($fname='', $lname='') {

    if(!empty($fname)) {
        $fname = mysql_real_escape_string($fname);
    }

    if(!empty($lname)) {
        $lname = mysql_real_escape_string($lname);
    }

    $alias = strtolower($fname).strtolower($lname);
    $sql = "Select ALIAS from table where ALIAS = '$alias'";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($query);
    $string_length = strlen($alias) - 1;
    $result_string = substr($alias, 0, $string_length);

    if(!$row) {
        print $alias;   // Is printing value
        return $alias;  // But here it returns null
    }
    else {
        $this->checkAlias($result_string);
    }

}
```

Comment: maybe you forgot a return before this line: `$this->checkAlias($result_string);`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You forgot to return the result of the recursion call:

```
return $this->checkAlias($result_string);
```

Answer (score 3):

You forgot the return keyword before `$this->checkAlias($result_string);`

Change your code to this:

```
public function checkAlias($fname='', $lname='') {

    if(!empty($fname)) {
        $fname = mysql_real_escape_string($fname);
    }

    if(!empty($lname)) {
        $lname = mysql_real_escape_string($lname);
    }

    $alias = strtolower($fname).strtolower($lname);
    $sql = "Select ALIAS from table where ALIAS = '$alias'";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($query);
    $string_length = strlen($alias) - 1;
    $result_string = substr($alias, 0, $string_length);

    if(!$row) {
        print $alias;   // Is printing value
        return $alias;  // But here it returns null
    }
    else {
        return $this->checkAlias($result_string);
    }
}
```

Because the first time the code will reach the *else* statement, and the second time it runs it will go in the *if* statement. The *if* returns the value, but in the *else* you don't do anything with it, so it returns it and you get your value.